# Active Record where query with complex conditional

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

Say I have a model Competition and each instance of it has_many Rounds. Each Round has an attribute :start_date. I want to fetch form the database the rounds that are about to start (i.e. sending an alert when we are 5 days before it starts.

I'm trying to build a Where Active Record query to avoid looping through the rounds and checking with a conditional in each round if the current date is within the described window until I find a match. With something like:

```
urgent_rounds = Round.none
pool.rounds.each do |round|
  urgent_rounds << round if DateTime.now.in_time_zone('Greenwich') > round.start_date - (60 * 60 * 24 * 5) && DateTime.now.in_time_zone('Greenwich') < round.start_date
end
```

It just doesn't feel right. So the way I know a Where with a conditional can be written is something like:

```
pool.rounds.where("attribute > ? and attribute < ?", value,  value)
```

In my case the first attribute should be `start_date` but the second, of course, can't be `start_date`. In fact can't be an attribute but a value resulting from the modification of the original start_date value, something like:

```
current_time_n_date = DateTime.now.in_time_zone('Greenwich')
pool.rounds.where("start_date - (60 * 60 * 24 * 5) < ? and start_date > ?", current_time_n_date,  current_time_n_date)
```

Is it possible to build a Where query such as above? How?

Comment: you can use between query with where.

Comment: Of course, Gabbar thanks for ending my mental block I need to go to sleep now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using BETWEEN as @Gabbar suggested. Below the code.

```
pool.rounds.where('start_date BETWEEN ? AND ?', DateTime.now.in_time_zone('Greenwich'), DateTime.now.in_time_zone('Greenwich') + 5.days)
```

Comment: ActiveRecord will produce the Between clause for you if you pass a Range object.  pool.rounds.where(start_date: (DateTime.now..5.days.from_now))